# Existe alguma função em que consigo montar um cabeçalho em um pdf, por meio da linguagem javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Estou começando agora a mexer com a linguagem HTML/Javascript e preciso gerar um pdf com um cabeçalho, mas não sei como, só achei código em php e não sei se funciona.

Answer (score 1):

#### Existe um plugin chamado [`jsPDF`](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/), experimente utilizar ele. Exemplo:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.text(20, 20, 'Criando um cabeçalho.');

  doc.setFont("courier");
  doc.setFontType("normal");
  doc.text(20, 30, 'Escrevendo num pdf.');


  doc.save('Teste.pdf');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```